# Is it possible to Expand the Dirac Delta function into the summation of a serie of certain Bessel functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, dirac-delta, bessel-functions

I am trying to solve an axisymmetric special plate problem, but stuck at the expansion of the Dirac Delta function $\delta(r)$ in the interval $[0,c]$, consisting of $1$ and orthonormal Bessel functions $J_0(\alpha_kr)$ with weight $r$. **$\alpha_k$ is the  $k_{th}$ positive root of $J_1(\alpha c)=0$** .

It has been proved in some books that $\{1,J_0(\alpha_kr)\}$ is the eigen-functions corresponding to the eigen-values $\{0,\alpha_k^2\}$ of a **singular Sturm-Liouville problem**, namely
$$
x^2 \frac{d^2X}{dx^2}+x\frac{dX}{dx}+\alpha^2xX=0
$$
and
$$
X'(c)=0
$$

(**It should be noted** that  $\alpha_k$ is the  $k_{th}$ positive root of $J_1(\alpha c)=0$, instead of $J_0(\alpha c)=0$, since the b.c. forces the derivative to vanish at boundaries. **Besides**, in my case, because of the other coupled equation's variable-separation solution, the basis funcion set is limited to  $\{1,J_0(\alpha_kr)\}$ described above.)

So, I think the funciton set should be complete in $[0,c]$ for any function meeting the above b.c..

But, Mathematica told me that
$$
\int_0^c\delta(r)rdr=0
$$
and
$$
\int_0^c\delta(r)J_0(\alpha_kr)rdr=0
$$

It seems that the Dirac Delta funciton cannot be expaned on this function set.

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: maybe the problem is that $\delta$ is not actually a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$

Comment: Thanks @FShrike . I am not sure. I use $\delta$ to represent the concentrated loads at the center of the plate. This method works well for beams, where the basis functions are ${cos( (2k-1)\pi x/L)}$.

Comment: Consider a small sphere centered at origin with radius $\epsilon$ and total "mass" $1$.

Comment: There is the limit representation $\delta(x)=\underset{\epsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\, J_{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\left(\frac{x+1}{\epsilon}\right)$ ([see here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/0011/)). The Mathematica evaluations are correct because the functions $r$ and $J_0(\alpha_kr)\, r$ both evaluate to $0$ at $r=0$.

Comment: I'm wondering if its possible to derive a [Fourier-Bessel series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-BesselSeries.html) to approximate $\delta(x)$ in the interval $(0, 1)$ based on an analytic representation of $\delta(x)$.

Comment: The [Calculating the coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Bessel_series#Calculating_the_coefficients) section of the Wikipedia article on Fourier-Bessel series gives a series representation for $\delta(x-y)$ in terms of Bessel J functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Initial Approach

The series representation for $\delta(x-y)$ defined at the end of the [Calculating the coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Bessel_series#Calculating_the_coefficients) section of the Wikipedia article on Fourier-Bessel series seems to suggest the representation

$$\delta(r)=\frac{2 (c+r)}{(2 c)^2}\ \underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{J_{\alpha}\left(\frac{j_{\alpha,k}}{2 c} c\right) J_{\alpha}\left(\frac{j_{\alpha,k}}{2 c} (c+r)\right)}{J_{\alpha+1}\left(j_{\alpha,k}\right){}^2}\tag{1}$$

converges (in a distributional sense) on the interval $(-c,c)$ where $j_{\alpha,k}$ is the $k^{th}$ positive root of $J_{\alpha}(r)=0$.

---

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (1) for $\delta(r)$ above evaluated at $\alpha=1$, $c=2$, and $K=10$ seems to be converging (in a distributional sense) on the interval $(-c,c)=(-2,2)$.

[image: Illustration of formula (1) for delta(r)]

**Figure (1):** Illustration of formula (1) for $\delta(r)$ evaluated at $\alpha=1$, $c=2$, and $K=10$

### Alternate Approach

The alternate approach is an attempt to derive a formula more consistent with the goals of the question.

---

Consider the formula

$$\delta'(r-c)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^K a(c,n)\, J_1\left(\frac{j_{1,n}}{2 c} r\right)\tag{2}$$

which I believe converges (in a distributional sense) on the interval $(0, 2 c)$ where $j_{1,k}$ is the $k^{th}$ positive root of $J_1(r)=0$ and

$$a(c,n)=\frac{\int\limits_0^{2 c} r\, \delta'(r-c)\, J_1\left(\frac{j_{1,n}}{2 c} r\right)\, dr}{\frac{1}{2} \left(2 c\, J_{1+1}\left(j_{1,n}\right)\right){}^2}=-\frac{j_{1,n}\, J_0\left(\frac{j_{1,n}}{2}\right)}{4 c^2\, J_2\left(j_{1,n}\right){}^2}\tag{3}.$$

---

Term-wise integration of formula (2) above using Mathematica results in the following formula

$$\delta(r-c)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^K b(c,n) \left(J_0\left(\frac{j_{1,n}}{2 c} r\right)-1\right)\tag{4}$$

where

$$b(c,n)=\frac{J_0\left(\frac{j_{1,n}}{2}\right)}{2 c\, J_2\left(j_{1,n}\right){}^2}\tag{5}$$

but formula (4) above seems to evaluate with an offset whereas the conjectured formula

$$\delta(r-c)=\frac{1}{2 c}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^K b(c,n)\, J_0\left(\frac{j_{1,n}}{2 c} r\right)\tag{6}$$

seems to converge (in a distributional sense) on the interval $(0,2 c)$ while eliminating this offset.

---

The conjectured formula (6) above leads to the following conjectured formula

$$\delta(r)=\frac{1}{2 c}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^K b(c,n)\, J_0\left(\frac{j_{1,n}}{2 c} (r+c)\right)\tag{7}$$

which seems to converge (in a distributional sense) on the interval $(-c, c)$ as illustrated in Figure (2) below where $c=\frac{3}{2}$.

[image: Illustration of formula (7) for delta(r)]

**Figure (2):** Illustration of conjectured formula (7) for $\delta(r)$ evaluated at $K=10$ (blue) and $K=20$ (orange) where $c=\frac{3}{2}$

---

I'm not sure if the [scaling property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry) $\delta(r)=2 c\,  \delta(2 c r)$ can be applied to the conjectured formula (7) above for $\delta(r)$ since this has the undesirable effect of decreasing the range of convergence.

---

### Another Conjectured Formula

Consider the following conjectured formula which is based on a conjectured formula user @Charles6 posted in a comment below

$$\delta(x-y)=\frac{2y}{c^2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^K d(y,c,n)\, J_0\left(\alpha(c,k)\, x\right)\tag{8}$$

where

$$d(y,c,n)=\frac{2 y\, J_0(\alpha(c,k)\, y)}{c^2\, J_0(\alpha(c,k)\, c){}^2}\tag{9}$$

and $\alpha(c,k)$ is the $k^{th}$ positive root of $J_1(c x)$. In other words $\alpha(c,k)=\frac{j_{1,k}}{c}$ where $j_{1,k}$ is the $k^{th}$ positive root of $J_1(x)$.

---

I believe formula (8) above evaluated at $c=2 y$ is exactly equivalent to formula (6) above evaluated at $c=y$ which is related to the equivalence of $J_0(j_{1,k})^2=J_2(j_{1,k})^2$ where $j_{1,k}$ is the $k^{th}$ positive root of $J_1(x)$.

---

Formula (8) above (assuming its correct) seems to suggest the following limit representation

$$\delta(x)=\underset{y\to 0}{\text{lim}}\ \left(\frac{2y}{c^2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^K d(y,c,n)\, J_0\left(\alpha(c,k)\, x\right)\right)\tag{10}$$

which perhaps converges (in a distributional sense) on the interval $(-c, c)$ as $y\to0$ and $K\to\infty$.

---

Figure (3) below illustrates formula (10) above evaluated at $c=1$, $y=10^{-4}$, and $K=20$.

[image: Illustration of conjectured formula (10) for delta(x)]

**Figure (3):** Illustration of conjectured formula (10) for $\delta(x)$

---

But something seems wrong with formula (10) since $\int\limits_{-1}^1 \delta(x)\,dx=1$ and there doesn't seem to be enough area under the curve in Figure (3) for it to integrate to $1$ (I believe the area is closer to $\frac{1}{10}$).

---

Note formula (10) above can be evaluated as

$$\delta(x)=\underset{y\to 0}{\text{lim}}\ \frac{2y}{c^2} \left(1+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^K  \hat{d}(y,c,n)\, J_0\left(\alpha(c,k)\, x\right)\right)\tag{11}$$

where

$$\hat{d}(y,c,n)=\frac{J_0(\alpha(c,k)\, y)}{J_0(\alpha(c,k)\, c){}^2}\tag{12}$$

so if formula (10) is on the right track, then perhaps the scaling factor $\frac{2y}{c^2}$ in formula (11) above is incorrect and needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks @Steven for you efforts, indeed. Sorry for not clearifying before that in my case, the basis function set is bounded to $\{ 1, J_0(\alpha_kr\}$ by another coupled function's variable-separation solution, where $\alpha_k$ has to be the $k_{th}$ positive root of $J_1(\alpha r)=0$ rather than $J_0(\alpha r)=0$. Otherwise, I cannot infer the unknowns from the equality of coefficients. Nonetheless, I think your proposal, using the analytical approximation of $\delta(r)$, could be on the track.

Comment: Hey, @Steven. It seems to be only one step away to the anwser. I traced back the citation you pointed out in the Wikipedia article on Fourier-Bessel series, and  found that $$ \delta (x-y)=2y/c^2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_0(\alpha_k x)J_0(\alpha_k y)\frac{2y}{R^2(J_0^2(\alpha_k c)+J_1^2(\alpha_k c))} $$ could be an representation of $\delta$ in $[0,c]$. But I don't known how to prove it.  (ref:Cahill, K.. Physical mathematics. Second edition. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2019. P.306, Eq.7.374)

Comment: More important to me is that how to convert this representation, $\delta (x-y)$ represented by $J_0(\alpha)_kx)J_0(\alpha_ky)$, to the form I need, $\delta (r)$ represented by $J_0(\alpha_kr)$. Please note that $\alpha_k$ is the $k_{th}$ root of $J_1(\alpha c)=0$.

Comment: This is the figure evaluated at $y=1/2, c=1$ with 30 terms.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDbhB.jpg

Comment: @Charles6 Assuming $R$ in your conjectured formula is really $c$, I believe your formula evaluated at $c=2 y$ is exactly equivalent to formula (6) in my answer above evaluated at $c=y$. Since $J_1\left(j_{1,k}\right){}^2=0$, I believe this comes down to the equivalence of $J_0\left(j_{1,k}\right){}^2=J_2\left(j_{1,k}\right){}^2$ where $j_{1,k}$ is the $k^{th}$ positive root of $J_1(r)$.

Comment: Thank you @Steven.  And yes, $R$ should be $c$ in my previous comments. Anyway, your anwser is marvelous. I was going to try eq.10 and check its legitimacy by the results. But **the dimension of variables didn't seem to be consistent in Eq.(10)** of your answer.

Comment: Let $q=F\delta(x)$ be the pressure beared by a plate, whoes dimension is $Force/(Length)^2$. Then $\delta(x)$ has the dimension of $1/(Length)^2$. Because $c$ represents the radius of the plate with dimension $Length$, we can deduce that **$y$ has the dimension of $1$** from the first term of Eq.(10). On the other hand, Eq.(9) shows that both $\alpha (c,k)y$ and $\alpha (c,k) c$ are the independent variables of the same Bessel function. They should have the same dimension. So, **$y$ should have the dimension of $Length$** as $c$ dose, **which contradicts the above conclusion**.

Comment: @Charles6 I'm not sure I understand the problem, but does $\underset{y\to 0}{\text{lim}}\, J_0(\alpha (c,k) \,y)=1$ help resolve your issue?

Comment: But something seems wrong with formula (10) since $\int\limits_{-1}^1 \delta(x)\,dx=1$ and there doesn't seem to be enough area under the curve in Figure (3) for it to integrate to $1$ (I believe the area is closer to $\frac{1}{10}$). Note formula (10) above is equivalent to formula (11) above, so if formula (10) is on the right track then perhaps the scaling factor $\frac{2y}{c^2}$ in formula (11) is incorrect and needs to be adjusted.